# How do I read exactly n bytes from a stream?

Tags: c#, .net, stream

This is a little more tricky than I first imagined. I'm trying to read n bytes from a stream.

The [MSDN claims](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/29tb55d8%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) that Read does not have to return n bytes, it just must return at least 1 and up to n bytes, with 0 bytes being the special case of reaching the end of the stream.

Typically, I'm using something like

```
var buf = new byte[size];
var count = stream.Read (buf, 0, size);

if (count != size) {
    buf = buf.Take (count).ToArray ();
}

yield return buf;
```

I'm hoping for exactly `size` bytes but by spec FileStream would be allowed to return a large number of 1-byte chunks as well. This must be avoided.

One way to solve this would be to have 2 buffers, one for reading and one for collecting the chunks until we got the requested number of bytes. That's a little cumbersome though.

I also had a look at [BinaryReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143295.aspx) but its spec also does not clearly state that n bytes will be returned for sure.

To clarify: Of course, upon the end of the stream the returned number of bytes may be less than `size` - that's not a problem. I'm only talking about not receiving n bytes even though they are available in the stream.

Comment: the `BinaryReader.ReadBytes(int)` returns the number of bytes requested; if the stream ends earlier, it will return what it read until that point (so less than requested).

Comment: @bosonix That would be convenient. Do you have a source for this information?

Comment: this is specified in the MSDN page https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.readbytes(v=vs.110).aspx and I also looked at the disassembled code.

Comment: @bosonix I see. It is stated rather unambigious there, and if the code matches, this seems to be the best solution. I am confused why I did not notice that method (apparently it _was_ available at the time I asked this question), and even Marc Gravell did not suggest it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A slightly more readable version:

```
int offset = 0;
while (offset < count)
{
    int read = stream.Read(buffer, offset, count - offset);
    if (read == 0)
        throw new System.IO.EndOfStreamException();
    offset += read;
}
```

Or written as an extension method for the `Stream` class:

```
public static class StreamUtils
{
    public static byte[] ReadExactly(this System.IO.Stream stream, int count)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[count];
        int offset = 0;
        while (offset < count)
        {
            int read = stream.Read(buffer, offset, count - offset);
            if (read == 0)
                throw new System.IO.EndOfStreamException();
            offset += read;
        }
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(offset == count);
        return buffer;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15):

Simply; you loop;

```
int read, offset = 0;
while(leftToRead > 0 && (read = stream.Read(buf, offset, leftToRead)) > 0) {
    leftToRead -= read;
    offset += read;
}
if(leftToRead > 0) throw new EndOfStreamException(); // not enough!
```

After this, `buf` should have been populated with exactly the right amount of data from the stream, or will have thrown an EOF.

Comment: this is not java, throw by value, do not use `new` operator

Comment: @Jiří I would love for you to expand on that, because yes: you're meant to use `new` when throwing in C# (unless you're re-throwing); the only common change I'd expect to see here is to use a utility method for that part instead of having the `throw` *in the same method*, so that the `throw` doesn't disable inlining  (which adds an extra stack-frame into the exception, but ... meh, you're already throwing). Are you perhaps thinking of C/C++?

Comment: Yeah, thought this was CPP didn't notice that flag, sorry about that - was just browsing some cpp questions to find solution and noticed this...

Answer (score 1):

Getting everything together from answers here I came up with the following solution. It relies on a source stream length. Works on .NET core 3.1

```
/// <summary>
/// Copy stream based on source stream length
/// </summary>
/// <param name="source"></param>
/// <param name="destination"></param>
/// <param name="bufferSize">
/// A value that is the largest multiple of 4096 and is still smaller than the LOH threshold (85K).
/// So the buffer is likely to be collected at Gen0, and it offers a significant improvement in Copy performance.
/// </param>
/// <returns></returns>
private async Task CopyStream(Stream source, Stream destination, int bufferSize = 81920)
{
    var buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
    var offset = 0;
    while (offset < source.Length)
    {
        var leftToRead = source.Length - offset;
        var lengthToRead = leftToRead - buffer.Length < 0 ? (int)(leftToRead) : buffer.Length;
        var read = await source.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, lengthToRead).ConfigureAwait(false);
        if (read == 0)
            break;
        await destination.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, lengthToRead).ConfigureAwait(false);
        offset += read;
    }
    destination.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
}
```