# How to Read the last line entered into the continuosly updating text file in c#

Tags: c#, text-files, filereader, file-handling

I have a text file which is continuously being updated from the Server data ..Now as per my requirement i have to read the last line added into the text file and show it into the windows form application text box.Once new line is added into the text file it should read that line and show into the text file ..
Please help me with your valuable suggestions.
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`FileSystemWatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) class to monitor any changes to the file you are interested in (you can use [`Filter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.filter(v=vs.110).aspx) property to limit this watcher to single file).
As for reading the last line from it you can use either of these approaches [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11625667/2974754), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/a/452945/2974754).

Comment: Simpler than approach two is Arin's (deleted) suggestion: save the file size each time the FileSystemWatcher fires; the new text is anything later.  For example, if the file size was 200 bytes and the file then has new text appended, this new text will be in bytes 201 through EOF.