# The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process when I count

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, filesystemwatcher

I've build a File System Watcher solution, and, I would to retrieve the changes made on log file, extracting only the added line, but I can not in this because I always error that the process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
My code is this for retrieve the added line is this:

```
using (var file = new FileStream(FileName,
                                        FileMode.Open,
                                        FileAccess.Read,
                                        FileShare.Read))

        using (var sr = new StreamReader(file))
        {
                try
                {
                    Thread thread = new Thread(delegate()
                    {
                        listBox1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() =>
                        {

                            listBox1.Items.Clear();//this is the listbox that list every added line and that I clear before of to be filled
                            string[] lines = File.ReadLines(fileName)
                                                 .Skip(LinecountStartPositionBUFF)
                                                 .Take(LinecountEndPosition - LinecountStartPositionBUFF)
                                                 .ToArray();
                            listBox1.Items.AddRange(lines);

                        }));
                    });

                    thread.Start();

                    while (thread.IsAlive)
                        Application.DoEvents();
                }

                catch
                { }

            return sr.ReadLine();
        }
```

Comment: Before you go any further, please rename your controls. (`listbox1` is **not** a good naming convention). BTW nor is using an empty `catch {}` block

Comment: Not related to your issue, but swallowing exceptions is bad practice. Add handling on your catch block

Comment: See [Read last line of text file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11625595/read-last-line-of-text-file) for a proper implementation. There's a lot wrong with your code.

Comment: thanks for your valuable suggestions. I'm a novice. May I have a sample code please for to start right? Thanks again in advance.

Comment: just for to be more clear, in my snippet, I would to try to select like SQL steatement, only the added line using 'LinecountStartPositionBUFF' and 'LinecountEndPosition'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not open the file in a `FileStream` and later access it via `File.ReadLines`, because `FileStream` locks the file. I would change the complete code.

Comment: May you please give me some advice on how to reach my goal  not using `File.ReadLines`? Thank you