# How to set length in stream without truncated?

Tags: c#, stream

Its stated that by using `Stream.SetLength` the stream is **truncated**.
[source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.setlength(v=vs.110).aspx)

I need to set the length of the stream **without** truncation.

Any build-in possibilities?

**UPDATE**:
I need to read a subset of a file. 
the file format: size + data(string format).

Im using `StreamReader`

**UPDATE2**:
Im also veryintrested in using `ReadLine` from the `StreamReader` class.

Comment: Then what do you expect to happen?

Comment: You missed the key part of the sentence, "*If the specified value is less than the current length of the stream*, the stream is truncated." If you set the length to less then the current length, what else is it supposed to do?

Comment: what overall problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: The only way to not truncate the stream is to make it longer, and then where does the extra data come from? If you make it shorter, again, where does the data go? Kind of like wanting to cut your legs off at the knees, but you don't want to be any shorter...

Comment: So you are only trying to read a part of the file? You can do this without `SetLength `.

Comment: @JeffMercado I need to read a subset of the file. the length is less. I don't want to change the file. just read

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7514101/how-do-i-read-exactly-n-bytes-from-a-stream)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to expose a sub section of my stream to a user](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6949441)

Answer (score 2):

> I need to read a subset of a file

OK, so you do not want to set the length actually. You want to read a particular length.

Write yourself a `Stream` subclass that reads only a certain amount of bytes. Then, you can wrap the file stream with that class and `StreamReader` will just work.

Or, if buffering the data is OK, you do this:

```
var limitedStream = new MemoryStream(new BinaryReader(myStream).ReadBytes(length));
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @usr's answer about creating a subclass Stream wrapper.  Here's a sample implementation which forwards all calls to the "inner" stream, but gets involved during reading or when asked for Length.  Anything involving writing is unsupported with this implementation.

I haven't fully tested this implementation and I welcome edits from the community:

```
sealed class StreamReadLimitLengthWrapper : Stream
{
    readonly Stream m_innerStream;
    readonly long m_endPosition;

    public StreamReadLimitLengthWrapper(Stream innerStream, int size)
    {
        if (innerStream == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("innerStream");
        if (size < 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("size");

        m_innerStream = innerStream;
        m_endPosition = m_innerStream.Position + size;
    }

    public override bool CanRead
    {
        get { return m_innerStream.CanRead; }
    }

    public override bool CanSeek
    {
        get { return m_innerStream.CanSeek; }
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override void Flush()
    {
        m_innerStream.Flush();
    }

    public override long Length
    {
        get { return m_endPosition; }
    }

    public override long Position
    {
        get
        {
            return m_innerStream.Position;
        }
        set
        {
            m_innerStream.Position = value;
        }
    }

    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        count = GetAllowedCount(count);
        return m_innerStream.Read(buffer, offset, count);
    }

    public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin)
    {
        return m_innerStream.Seek(offset, origin);
    }

    public override void SetLength(long value)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    public override bool CanTimeout { get { return m_innerStream.CanTimeout; } }

    public override int ReadTimeout
    {
        get
        {
            return m_innerStream.ReadTimeout;
        }
        set
        {
            m_innerStream.ReadTimeout = value;
        }
    }

    public override int WriteTimeout
    {
        get
        {
            return m_innerStream.ReadTimeout;
        }
        set
        {
            m_innerStream.ReadTimeout = value;
        }
    }

    public override IAsyncResult BeginRead(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
    {
        count = GetAllowedCount(count);
        return m_innerStream.BeginRead(buffer, offset, count, callback, state);
    }

    public override IAsyncResult BeginWrite(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    public override void Close()
    {
        // Since this wrapper does not own the underlying stream, we do not want it to close the underlying stream
    }

    public override Task CopyToAsync(Stream destination, int bufferSize, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return m_innerStream.CopyToAsync(destination, bufferSize, cancellationToken);
    }

    public override int EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
    {
        return m_innerStream.EndRead(asyncResult);
    }

    public override Task FlushAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return m_innerStream.FlushAsync(cancellationToken);
    }

    public override Task<int> ReadAsync(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        count = GetAllowedCount(count);
        return m_innerStream.ReadAsync(buffer, offset, count, cancellationToken);
    }

    public override int ReadByte()
    {
        int count = GetAllowedCount(1);
        if (count == 0)
            return -1;

        return m_innerStream.ReadByte();
    }

    public override Task WriteAsync(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    public override void WriteByte(byte value)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    private int GetAllowedCount(int count)
    {
        long pos = m_innerStream.Position;
        long maxCount = m_endPosition - pos;
        if (count > maxCount)
            count = (int)maxCount;
        return count;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're asking the wrong question here.  The `Length` of a stream is the known amount of bytes are available to be read from the stream.  Setting the length of the stream alters the source to ensure it uses the length specified.

---

Since you merely want to limit how much you read from the stream, just read as much as you need and close it.  You don't need to do anything else.

Since it appears you're trying to read a text file, just go with the normal file reading patterns and come up with an appropriate stop condition.  You won't even need a stream, the `File` class provides simple ways to read the lines of a file.

```
foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(path))
{
    // do something with line...
    if (line == "end of interesting section")
        break;
}
```