# Amazon S3 File Full of Zeros

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm downloading a PDF file from an AWS S3 bucket using the official client in C#. It appears to download the whole file, but everything is 0s after 8192 (0x2000) bytes.
See below (original file on left, S3 download on right):

[image]

Any ideas as to why this is happening would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the code:

```
var client = new AmazonS3Client(
    new AmazonS3Config
    {
        RegionEndpoint = RegionEndpoint.EUWest1
    });

var transferUtility = new TransferUtility(client);

var request = new TransferUtilityOpenStreamRequest
{
    BucketName = bucketName,
    Key = key
};

using (var stream = transferUtility.OpenStream(request))
{
    var bytes = new byte[stream.Length];

    stream.Read(bytes, 0, (int)stream.Length);

    stream.Close();

    return bytes;
}
```

Thanks in advance,

Steve.

Comment: `Read` returns an int with the number of bytes it read. It isn't guaranteed to be the length you requested. With S3 I've seen as little as 128 bytes in a single read.

Comment: Have you verified the the file downloads correctly through the S3 interface?

Comment: Ah, ok, thanks John. I'll guess I keep calling Read until the full stream has been read. Thanks.

Comment: BlueWater86, yes I have - it does download correctly via the UI. I think John's probably hit upon the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone else hitting this issue, it was a case of having to repeatedly call Read on the stream until all bytes have been received:

```
using (var stream = transferUtility.OpenStream(request))
{
    var position = 0;
    var length = stream.Length;

    var bytes = new byte[length];

    do
    {
        position += stream.Read(bytes, position, (int)(stream.Length - position));
    } while (position < length);

    stream.Close();

    return bytes;
}
```

Thanks to John for pointing that out.

Edit:

Or check out this extension method kindly pointed out by JohnLBevan: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24412022/361842

Comment: FYI: Andrei provides a useful extension method for this same scenario here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24412022/361842 - this has one useful bonus compared to your implementation in that it throws an exception should you reach the end-of-stream prematurely; i.e. rather than getting stuck in an infinite loop.